# Scrapy: Use particular python version

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, versioning

I tried to run scrapy in my centOs. Since centos comes with python2.6 installed and scrapy requires python2.7, I tried creating virtual environment and ran scrapy inside that, but I still get error

```
Scrapy 0.24.4 requires Python 2.7.
```

These are my output on starting the spider

```
(scrapyproject)[imadmin@IM03 tutorial]$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
(scrapyproject)[imadmin@IM03 tutorial]$ scrapy gen_spider
Scrapy 0.24.4 requires Python 2.7
```

I even tried setting up a shell alias:

```
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

This also didnt work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to install scrapy inside the virtual environment (i.e. run `pip install scrapy` after activating virtual env "scrapyproject").

The way you are doing it now, `scrapy` command cannot be found inside virtual env, so it is called outside of virtual env.

P.S. Delete the alias.

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is scrapy gen_spider command is looking for the scrapy installation which is outside your virtualenv.

Modify your $PATH to include scrapy installation (which is inside your virtualenv) before everything else.

Example:

export PATH=/root/virtualenv-1.11.6/localenv/bin:/root/virtualenv-1.11.6/localenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin